# Site and List (Library) Permissions with Lookup column

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, external-users

After sharing a Sub-Site with an external user (requiring Microsoft live login) the external user cannot access a document library within the site.
I'm getting the "Sorry, you don't have access to this page" response.

Initially, when I tested sharing on a different site collection, the external user could access the library fine.
Differences between test library and current library:

- Current library has Approve/Reject and Versioning
- Current library has a Column (defined at the top site) that is a lookup to a list (also on the top site).
- Library page has a Query URL String web part which provides a filter targetting the lookup column.
- Library has 2010 and 2013 workflows.
- Librarys new and modify form have been modified through web-editor, runs Javascript.

`Top Site**
 - ListA
 - Int Sites
 - Ext Site Hub
   - Ext SiteB
     - LibraryC`

List A is at `s.sharepoint.com/sites/Top/Lists/ListA`
External Site B is at `s.sharepoint.com/sites/Top/Ext/ExtB`
Library C is at `s.sharepoint.com/sites/Top/Ext/ExtB/LibC`
**Columns and Content Types for LibraryC are defined here

In O365 Admin I have selected `Allow external users who accept sharing invitations and sign in as authenticated users`.
The in SiteB I clicked the Share button on the site ribbon (next to the Follow button), and invited the external user, assigning them to Team Member (Edit).
Once the email arrived, I followed the link making sure to log in the with the correct Live account.
This took me to SiteB, and when I tried to navigate to the library, I got Page permission error.

I have tried removing and re-adding the users permissions.
I have tried making the site/library permissions unique/inherit.

What have I missed?
Is this actually possible?
Has Sharepoint hidden some weird set of permissions for this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out:

Quick Links are different between different people/groups.
The Library wasn't showing in the Quick Links so I assumed that I couldn't access it.

Document Version Draft Item Security was set to Approve + Author only.
When following a direct link, it would take me to an empty library.

Solution: Setting Draft Item Security to 'Any user who can read items' and adding the library to the other users quick links.